# Wordpress regular query not respecting sticky posts

Tags: wordpress

I have this query on my homepage and it works great except when I have `sticky posts`. The problem is that it should show only `sticky posts` (**that are 30**) and it show some of the last posts.

Also, the second page shows some of the `sticky posts` also.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('paged='.$paged.'&showposts=30&cat=-1,-4491&orderby=desc&page=$page');
```

Comment: WP_Query creates a brand new custom query from scratch, it doesn't replicate the main blog query so you have to tell if you want it to do something with sticky posts. What exactly are you trying to do, e.g. do you want the sticky posts showing up first in your queried results? Or excluded from the queried results so you can display them separately?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I want the sticky posts showing up first in queried results.